1980s technical book serif all caps font
i'm searching this font. It's from a technical book/document about a nuclear reactor project, from the 1984. I think was printed by LIPS, Lyon in France, but i'm struggling to found out this typeface. Thanks


Some flavor of Stymie perhaps. That A with the top bar should make searching pretty easy at font search sites.

This is Rockwell Bold Italic. Different cuts of Rockwell have slightly different weights: the Monotype version looks slightly lighter than the sample.

